# python logging root logger does not show info even if I set the level to INFO

Tags: python, logging

I created the following script. Could any of you explain to me why the output is like what shows below

#### Source

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

print('debug', logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG))
print('info', logger.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO))
print('warning', logger.isEnabledFor(logging.WARNING))
print('error', logger.isEnabledFor(logging.ERROR))

logger.debug('debug')
logger.info('info')
logger.warning('warning')
logger.error('error')

logging.debug('debug')
logging.info('info')
logging.warning('warning')
logging.error('error')
```

#### Output

```
debug True
info True
warning True
error True
warning
error
DEBUG:root:debug
INFO:root:info
WARNING:root:warning
ERROR:root:error
```

Specifically

1. what is the difference between `logger.info` and `logging.info` here
2. how come that `logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG)` is `True` while `logger.debug('debug')` does not show anything
3. how come that `logger.info` has no output but `logging.info` has

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A few things to clarify:

1. Default log level for root logger is `WARNING`
2. Root logger is not initialized if you do nothing, that is, without any handlers or formatter set up:

   ```
   >>> import logging
   >>> logging.root.handlers
   []
   ```

Okay, but you found out the problem: when logging level set to `DEBUG`, the root logger is not working as expected. Debug messages are ignored. With the same not configured root logger, warning messages output normally. Why is that?

Keep in mind we don't have any handler for root logger right now. But looking into the [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1544-L1551), we do see:

```
    if (found == 0):
        if lastResort:
            if record.levelno >= lastResort.level:
                lastResort.handle(record)
        elif raiseExceptions and not self.manager.emittedNoHandlerWarning:
            sys.stderr.write("No handlers could be found for logger"
                             " \"%s\"\n" % self.name)
            self.manager.emittedNoHandlerWarning = True
```

Which means, we have a `lastResort` for backup if no handler is found. You can refer to the definition of `lastResort`, it is initialized with logging level `WARNING`. Meanwhile, debug messages don't have this backup so they are ignored when no handler is set.

For your questions:

1. These two loggers are identical, since the root logger is returned when `getLogger()` receives no arguments.
2. See below:

   > Logger.isEnabledFor(lvl)
   >
   > Indicates if a message of severity lvl would
   >   be processed by this logger. This method checks first the module-level
   >   level set by logging.disable(lvl) and then the logger’s effective
   >   level as determined by getEffectiveLevel().
3. Calling any logging functions in `logging` module will initialize the root logger with `basicConfig()` which adds a default handler, so that the subsequent calls on `logger` will also work.

What you should do is, use `logging.basicConfig()` to set up a default handler for root logger and messages will be output according to the logger level and message level.

Comment: Thanks @Ares Ou. I get your point on the behavior of `logger`. Could you also explain a little why `logging.debug` works if `logging.debug` and `logger.debug` are the same thing.

Comment: They are all `root logger`, but when you call `logging.debug`, `basicConfig()`  called, which make the difference. if you call `logger.debug('debug')
` after the code above, you will see the output `DEBUG:root:debug` , then you will get understood.

Comment: You mean that any call to `logging.log` will initialize the root logger with `basicConfig()` if it is not already initialized?

Comment: No! you can read [logging.\[log|debug|...\]](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1950-L1958).  `basicConfig()` only called when `root` has no `handler`

Comment: If I understand correctly, the logger instance is processing INFO and DEBUG, but the (default) handler isn't? Maybe you could clarify the difference between logger level and handler level.

Answer (score 2):

[getLogger](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5f908005ce16b06d5af7b413264009c4b062f33c/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1832?utm_source=djinn) creates an instance of Logger class if argument `name` is added. Otherwise it returns root logger. So in this case the program is using the common logger as functions `logging.debug`, `logging.info`, `logging.warning`, `logging.info`